# Ошибка Uncaught SyntaxError: return not in function

Tags: jquery, ajax, return

Данный код возвращает по клику на ссылку по аяксу html-данные

```
    <script >
        $(function get_sample2() {
        
          $('.content').on("click",'.reg-page-mail',function sample2() {
          $.ajax({
          url: 'data.php?action=sample2',
          success: function getdata2(htmldata){
            $('.content').html('');
            $(htmldata).appendTo('.content');     
                        }
                    });
                });
        });
    </script>
```

. Все отрабатывает , данные присылаются и вставляются на странице , но в консоли  браузера появляется ошибка со следующим текстом : Uncaught SyntaxError: return not in function . Просмотрел в инете решения, но ничего похожего не нашел.

Comment: Значит видимо где-то внутри этих данных есть кривой скрипт, ищите

Comment: данные просто верстка  и все :   <div class="reg-page">
   <div class="aut-reg">
   <p class="aut-reg-text">Вход </p>  
   <p class="aut-reg-sms">Только для зарегистрированных пользователей</p>
  </div>
  <form class="get-code">
   <input  type="text" class="get-code-mask-mail" placeholder="Email" required> 
   <button type="submit" class="get-code-act-but" >Продолжить</button>   
   <a class="reg-page-tel">Войти  номеру телефона</a>

  </form>
 </div>

Comment: Уверены что «все»? Проверяли конкретно содержимое переменной `htmldata` или вкладку «Сеть» в браузерных инструментах разработчика например?

Comment: Спасибо большое, проблема решена. Из верстки надо было удалить пустые тэги script. Даже не знаю, почему из-за них выскакивала данная ошибка)